# What's the difference between is.seekg(0) and is.seekg(0, is.end)? "is" is an input stream

Tags: c++

Side-question: Are there any tips for understanding cppreference.com? I really struggle to understand and it's sad because there's so much info there

Comment: C++ is complicated and as a result the documentation is often complicated. Often getting a leg up by reading the simplified, and sometimes incorrect, documentation on cplusplus.com  helps. Microsoft documentation is also generally easier to read, but it can bring with it its own problems.

Comment: `0, end` means move the read position to 0 bytes from the end of the stream. Typically this would be the end of a file. Just `0` means seek to the absolute 0 point in the stream, the beginning. This would be the start of a file. In a non-file stream exactly what begin and end mean is more fluid. For example, in a network stream the true beginning of the stream may no longer be available, and the end... no one knows where the actual end will be until the connection is closed.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks a lot. I really appreciate.

Comment: cppreference is a good site to use as a reference, but not what I'd use as a tutorial.  In my opinion, it's not an alternative to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Some examples of usage are "hidden" in the desription of `std::ios_base::seekdir`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/seekdir